# OpenCV with python, capture mixed up

Tags: python, opencv

I have bought a raspberry pi and using an Archlinux image SD, Im trying to do learn about computer vision because Im planning to attach the rapsberry pi to an arduino board and do some robots.

Im trying to use opencv with python, so I followed and a tutorial to install opencv on Archlinux and tried this code:

```
import cv2.cv as cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  640)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

print "Captured "
cv.SaveImage("output.jpg",img3)
```

Im having a couple of problems. Im getting these errors

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

I think that they are warnings, because the execution ends and "output.jpg" is created, but the image is messed up. I include the image so you can see how it looks like.

Also, I can change the resolution to 320x240 because it just creates a whole black image.

I've been searching for solutions all in the internet during the past 2 days but Im on a dead end... So I would really thank anyone who could help me with this.

Thanks![image]

Comment: I do believe you should accept more answers if you want people to help. Just saying! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your comment :(

Comment: Underneath the score of every answer there is an accept "check box" which you can turn green. You have asked 13 question but only accepted an answer in 30% of the cases. It can turn people of from helping...

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I didnt notice that. I didnt really understand what that "tick" was for. Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: I figured it might be like that (because I done it myself). No problem :)

Comment: What is this img3 variable in the SaveImage call. Just a typo error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found my issue... It looks like if I do a time.sleep(3) after opening the camera the pictures are being captured corretly.

Im not 100% sure if thats the case but it has been working since I did that. I'll keep you posted if this works on my next tests, but for now I would recommend to do that.